Indesign batch image swapping
Does anyone know how I can batch relink one set of images in Indesign to another set of images. To give context I do a lot of work with sports trading cards graphics. I would like to be able to automatically be able to change say 10 versions of a card design flat tif (that has a white background) to 10 versions of the same card design tif but has a blue background, in one go. Both sets of cards need to keep their original names.

I think how you accomplish this depends on how the file is setup. Can you use master pages? Data Merge with linked backgrounds? Use one file, then overwrite that file and keep backups in a sub folder? Then you only have to refresh the link not re-add.

Select one link in the Document and then.....Links Panel Menu > Relink to folder... choosing a folder with your new images.
If the images are all titled the same, they should all replace. So, title all the tiffs the same, but put them in separate folders.
e.g.:

"White" folder

tiff01.tiff
tiff02.tiff


"Blue" folder

tiff01.tiff
tiff02.tiff



If you select White/tiff01 in the document, Relink to Folder, and choose the Blue folder, INDD should then update both tiff01 and tiff02 to the files in the Blue folder.

This method has been very handy for me if all the images are the same dimensions/ppi but just have some visual differences. And using the Object Layer control for each image would just be a lot of unnecessary effort.

Note the options when relinking to a folder, although I've never used it, you can specifically relink everything to a particular suffix within a folder - i.e. relink all [originalname].tiff files to [originalname].psd files. I imagine, quite handy if you use lower res images for placement only in the INDD file.

Thanks so much for replying, looking back at what I've written I should have phrased the question differently in that the files names are unique, so example tiff01.tiff, tiff02.tiff etc need to swap out for tiff01a.tiff, tiff02a.tiff

Even if the images are different, you can title them the same in a different directory. There are Finder/FileExplorer utilities to quickly batch rename files. I'd just keep a separate backup of all the images with their unique names as well.

Thanks Scott for your reply, the problem I have is that the files that I'm swapping out to can't change name as they are then supplied to my client and their original names have to stay intact (I'm creating print files (placing my photoshop files into indesign) and then also supplying the same phtoshop file to be used in an app).

Okay, well I don't know of any other method. You probably could find a script somewhere, but I imagine it's going to rely on user interaction to confirm every link. I've honestly just never looked for one. You can just remove the currently linked folder and when opening the file, and asked to correct missing links... link to new file.. and then keep relinking because INDD will ask above every link (but you probably know that)

I had previously seen a script that might do what I want by batch renaming the links from within Indesign but the download page just goes to an error page. https://www.marspremedia.com/software/indesign/links-rename-from-csv. Maybe I need to ask where I can find a bespoke script writer.

Scroll to the bottom of that page. There are links.

Unfortunately those links are for localising the language not the actual script.

https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/renaming-links-for-already-placed-image-files/td-p/12594593
